# Jest Unit testing for conditional elements with react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, react-hook-form

Im having a react hook form and some validation messages. I need to unit test this component. But all the time my conditional elements are not being rendered or updated. I've tried `wrapper.update();` but it's not serving the purpose.

My Component:

```
<form data-test='login-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
   <input data-test='password' name='password'
      ref={register({
           required: 'Password Required',
           minLength: {
              value: 6,
              message: 'Password should be 6 char long' ,
           },
          })}
    />
    {errors.password && (
       <p data-test='password-error'>
          {(errors.password as any).message}
       </p>
    )}
 <button data-test='login-submit'>
    Submit
 </button>
</form>
```

Unit Testing:

```
const setup = (): ShallowWrapper =>
      shallow(<LoginForm  />);

 describe('Login Form Component', () => {
   let wrapper: ShallowWrapper;
   test('expect to show password required validation messages', async () => {
  
   wrapper = setup();
   const loginButton = wrapper.find(`[data-test='password-error']`);

   loginButton.simulate('click');

   wrapper.update();

   const emailError = wrapper.find(`[data-test='email-error']`);
   expect(emailError.length).toBe(1);
 });
});
```

This never passes.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `
const emailError = wrapper.find(`[data-test='email-error']`);
   expect(emailError.length).toBe(1);
`

did you mean `const passwordError = wrapper.find(`[data-test='password-error']`);` ?

Comment: @AndangRianDimas yes that was a typo, in the question, corrected

Comment: Instead of simulating button click try simulating form submit. But in my experience it's way better to test react-hook-form with react0testing-library than enzyme.